How to group alt y axis with highcharts
I have a weird one.
I have a chart that requires 2 yaxis.
They both need to be tied to the same value, however, the right needs to have these groups.
here is the jsfiddle
(note: currently this fiddle is showing detached alt y axis)
What makes this somewhat more tricky, is the values on the right need to correspond to values on the left.
here is the breakdown;
{
    "7381967.213114754": {
        "title": "Contribution",
        "value": 200000
    },
    "5332786.8852459015": {
        "title": "Affluent",
        "value": 150000
    },
    "3392537.313432836": {
        "title": "Comfortable",
        "value": 100000
    },
    "2832835.8208955224": {
        "title": "Choices",
        "value": 85000
    },
    "1536428.5714285714": {
        "title": "No Frills",
        "value": 50000
    }
}

So in otherwords, if the value on the right axis has a value of 5332786, it needs to show 'Affluent/150k'.
How can I achieve this?

Just to make sure, you'd like to mantain current y-axis ticks that are rendered on the left side, whilst altering the right side y-axis? You could try using chart.alignThreshold which manages to align ticks on different scaled axes.
